# tikz coordinate calculations gone wild

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I'm quite a bit baffled why my coordinate calculations are coming out so differently.  All coordinates are where I expect them to be, **except** coordinate `Z`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

%% Attempt 01
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \draw[blue]  (  0:20)  arc(0:90:20);    

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red] 
           (0,0)                 coordinate [label=135:P] (Q) 
                  -- +( 90:20)   coordinate (B)  -- +( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )  coordinate (Bn) node {$Bn$}
              (B) -- +(0:20)     coordinate (Bl) -- +( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                  -- +(180:20)   coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

Same as example above except that $B$ is defined by \verb=(30:20)=
instead of \verb=(90:20)= relative to \verb=(0,0)=.  Also, I omitted
\verb!step=1! from the \verb=help lines=.

%% Attempt 02---same as attempt 01 except for (1) the placement definition
%% of coordinate "B" and (2) not "step=1" for the "help lines".
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \draw[blue]  (  0:20)  arc(0:90:20);    

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red,opacity=0.50] 
           (0,0)                 coordinate [label=135:P] (Q) 
                  -- +( 30:20)   coordinate (B)  -- +( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )  coordinate (Bn) node {$Bn$}
              (B) -- +(0:20)     coordinate (Bl) -- +( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                  -- +(180:20)   coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why are the coordinate calculations---for what seems to me to be the same thing---turning out so differently?

**Minor question**

Why must I specify "step=1" to get my help lines to look correctly?  Without `step=1`, I only get a five-by-five grid.

Comment: About the minor question: The default setting of `step` is `1cm`, that's why you get a 5x5 grid if your unit vectors are `0.2cm` long.

Comment: @jake. Doesn't that seem buggy that `step` is not set relative to the units I've specified?

Comment: @jldiaz.  I expect `Z` to be where `X` is.  It's exactly the same coordinate calculation.

Comment: @A.Ellett: I wouldn't call it buggy, you're just expecting something it doesn't do. It behaves exactly as it's specified in the manual.

Comment: @JLDiaz.  I think you're misunderstanding my question.  I want to know why when I do exactly the same coordiante calculations for `Z` and for `X` I get an answer placed in completely different places.

Comment: You are at the second row moving the path to (B) and then everything with `+(...)` becomes relative to `(B)`.

Comment: @percuße.  Argh!  Now I see that.  Thank you.  That helps a lot.

Comment: Dear moderators, I don't really know what to do with this post.  This was really just bad proof-reading on my part.  @percuße pointed out my mistake.  If I delete, then JLDiaz looses his rep points, right?  Maybe we should just close this as too localized?

Comment: @A.Ellett Just leave it as it is. I don't see any problems about it. Especially after your comments for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the line which places the X node and the one which places the Z node is that in the first one you are using absolute coordinates, while in the second one you are using relative coordinates because you preceded the coordinates with a `+` sign.

The `+` is not required since you are not giving the new coordinate as a displacement with respect other, but instead you are computing the new coordinates using a calc expression. You can remove the `+` in all your paths (at least in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

%% Attempt 01
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \path  (  0:20)   coordinate (A);
    \draw[blue]  (A) arc(0:90:20);

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red]
           (0,0)                 coordinate [label=135:P] (Q)
                  -- +( 90:20)   coordinate (B)  -- ( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )  coordinate (Bn) node {$B$}
              (B) -- +(0:20)     coordinate (Bl) -- ( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                  -- +(180:20)   coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

Same as example above except that $B$ is defined by \verb=(30:20)=
instead of \verb=(90:20)= relative to \verb=(0,0)=.  Also, I omitted
\verb!step=1! from the \verb=help lines=.

%% Attempt 02---same as attempt 01 except for (1) the placement definition
%% of coordinate "B" and (2) not "step=1" for the "help lines".
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \path  (  0:20)   coordinate (A);
    \draw[blue]  (A) arc(0:90:20);

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red,opacity=0.50]
           (0,0)                 coordinate [label=135:P] (Q)
                  -- +( 30:20)   coordinate (B)  -- ( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )  coordinate (Bn) node {$B$}
            (B)   -- +(0:20)     coordinate (Bl) -- ( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                  -- +(180:20)   coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

## Update

Based on the comments and on a better understanding of the intended output, I suggest to completely eliminate relative coordinates (those beginning with `+`) in your path, and replacing those for explicit calculations (which can involve polar coordinates). So, for example, to get a point 20 units to the right of `(B)`, use `($(B)+(0:20)$)`, instead of moving the origin to `(B)` and then write `+(0:20)`.

Mixing absolute and relative coordinates make difficult to guess and control the result. Use explicit calculations to a better understanding and control. With this approach your code would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

%% Attempt 01
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20,step=1] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \path  (  0:20)   coordinate (A);
    \draw[blue]  (A) arc(0:90:20);

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red]
           (0,0)                        coordinate [label=135:P] (Q)
                   -- ($(Q)+(90:20)$)   coordinate (B)  -- ( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )  coordinate (Bn) node {$B$}
               (B) -- ($(B)+(0:20)$)    coordinate (Bl) -- ( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                   -- ($(B)+(180:20)$)  coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}

Same as example above except that $B$ is defined by \verb=(30:20)=
instead of \verb=(90:20)= relative to \verb=(0,0)=.  Also, I omitted
\verb!step=1! from the \verb=help lines=.

%% Attempt 02---same as attempt 01 except for (1) the placement definition
%% of coordinate "B" and (2) not "step=1" for the "help lines".
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
    %% why does this draw a 5 by 5 grid when I don't specify "step=1"???
    \draw[help lines,blue!20] (0,0) grid (20,20);
    %% quarter circle
    \path  (  0:20)   coordinate (A);
    \draw[blue]  (A) arc(0:90:20);

    %% Coordinates "B", "Bn", "Bl", "Br" all come out where I expect
    %% Coordinate  "Z" is not where I expected it.
    \path  [draw,line width=2pt,red,opacity=0.50]
           (0,0)                 coordinate [label=135:P] (Q)
                  -- ($(Q)+(30:20)$)    coordinate (B)  -- ( $ (B) !-1em! (Q) $ )   coordinate (Bn) node {$B$}
             (B)  -- ($(B)+(0:20)$)     coordinate (Bl) -- ( $ (B) !0.5! (Bl) $ )  coordinate [label=90:Z] (Z)
                  -- ($(B)+(180:20)$)   coordinate (Br)
              ;

    %% Coordinate "X" goes where I thought coordinate "Z" would have gone too
    \draw ( $ (B) !0.5!(Bl) $ ) coordinate [label=90:X] (X) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result (I hope I got it right this time):

[image]

Comment: Almost! :)  But now `Bl` is not placed 20 "units" to the left of `B`.  This is really just a boiled down version of something much bigger.  Most of the relative coordinates are needed because I'm placing "most" coordinates relative to the center of a circle.  `Z` is the one exception.  But, I can draw that absolutely on its own, though I have to do that after I've completed drawing all the other relative coordinates.  Thanks though.

Comment: Actually, it's `Z`, `Bl`, and `Br` that are the exceptions.  But from this snippet I can see your point about the *apparent* lack of a need for all the relative coordinates.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  But I disagree with making all the calculations absolute.  The point of the relative coordinates is that I can change where I place `Q` and the whole picture will move with `Q`.  Your method will work, but only through a fair amount of convoluted calculations when `tikz` already provides a means to relativizing coordinates with respect to a given one.  My mistake was to forget that my anchoring coordinate was `Q` and not `B`.